# How do I get WebBrowsers url from the main Window C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have no idea how to get the Url from the WebBrowser that gets created with c# code and does not exist in the Xaml before the code is execeuted.. The AddTabItem() function is called at the start at the program and later on if user wants to add more TabItems user can click on the add button.

```
  public List<TabItem> tabItem;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        try {
            InitializeComponent();
            //nardimo array za TabItem
            tabItem = new List<TabItem>();

            //Dodamo zaznamek (tabItem)






            TabItem novTab = this.AddTabItem();


           //bajndam tab
            tabControl.DataContext = tabItem;
            tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
public TabItem AddTabItem()
    {
        int count = tabItem.Count;
        TabItem tab = new TabItem();



        tab.Header = string.Format("Zavihek {0}", count+1);
        tab.Name = string.Format("zavihek{0}", count);



        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

        wb.Name = string.Format("Brskalnik{0}", count);

        string a = "http://www.google.com";

        wb.Navigate(a);
        Url.Text = a;
        tab.Content = wb;

        tabItem.Insert(count, tab);


        return tab;

    }
```

Then user can search on the Web and wanted to make a bookmark.. so how do I get the Url from the site when he clicks on the add bookmark button? How do I access the WebBrowser since it is not located in the Xaml code? Keep in mind I have to add bookmarks from the second window and not the main one. I am really sorry for my bad English and would be really happy if someone could help <3 Thank you guys

Comment: You can get the selected or current tab from tabcontrol and get the child web browser control and get its url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is:

```
wb.Source.AbsoluteUri
```

If you drop a WebBrowser on your window and call it "wb", and a Button then you can do this in the code behind:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow 
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            wb.Navigate("http://google.com");
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(wb.Source.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the references that you add to the `List<TabItem>`:

```
WebBrowser wb = tabItem[tabItem.Count - 1].Content as WebBrowser;
string url = wb.Source.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
```